# Quotient Group of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ and a Lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am working on problem 2 of the [Rutgers 2017 Fall Algebra Qualifier](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/docman-lister/math-main/academics/graduate/qualifying-exam/1265-wq-new-format-sample/file) where we are tasked with determining the structure of $\mathbb{Z}^4 /S$ where $S$ is the group generated by the vectors $(5,-2,-4,1)$, $(-5,4,4,1)$, $(0,6,0,6)$.

So the first thing I noted was that

$$(5,-2,-4,1) + (-5,4,4,1) = (0,2,0,2).$$

So it follows the third vector given $(0,6,0,6)$ is in the span of first two, and so the question remains to show:

Find $\mathbb{Z}^4 / \lbrace a (5,-2,-4,1)  + b (-5,4,4,1), a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$

Now I tried to look for similar problems to this to make sense of it and came across the following: [Is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/((6,5),(3,4))$ is finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234997/is-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-6-5-3-4-is-finitely-generated)

But I'm not sure how to use the matrix techniques there correctly and rigorously.

---

So I now I'm working with equivalence classes but the ease with which one can declare $$ \mathbb{Z} / k\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_k$$ seems to be lost when I move into the 2 basis vector situation.

Comment: The keyword to look up is Smith normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Comment: There are a bunch of posts on this topic: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546751/finding-an-explicit-isomorphism-from-mathbbz4-h-to-mathbbz-oplus-m), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422919/suggestions-for-computing-mathbbzi3-k-where-k-langle1-2-1-0-0-5/), for example.

Comment: @Quasicoherent how to efficiently find those links? I tried approach0 out too but it seems I still could dig them up

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I'm not sure how to find them.  I just had answered these sorts of questions several times, so I bookmarked them.  Googling `site:math.stackexchange.com smith normal form` brought up [this relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198560/question-on-smith-normal-form-and-isomorphism), but you'd have to know the Smith normal form is the right thing to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A:\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}\ZZ^2\to\ZZ^4$ be the map sending $e_1$ to $(5,-2,-4,1)$ and $e_2$ to $(-5,4,4,1)$. Let's call the group you care about $G$. Then $G=\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}}\coker A$. Then
let $B:\ZZ^2\to\ZZ^2$ and $C:\ZZ^4\to\ZZ^4$ be automorphisms. Then the following diagram commutes,
$$\require{AMScd}\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}
\begin{CD}
\ZZ^2 @>A>> \ZZ^4@>>>G@>>>0\\
@VBVV @VVCV @VVDV\\
\ZZ^2 @>CAB\inv>> \ZZ^4@>>>G'@>>>0,\\
\end{CD}
$$
where $G'=\coker CAB\inv$, and $D$ is the induced map $\coker A \to \coker CAB\inv$. Then since $B$ and $C$ are isomorphisms, $D$ is too. You can either cite the five lemma or do the diagram chase yourself to prove it.

The point is to determine the structure of $G$, we can freely compose automorphisms with $A$ to get a nicer matrix, for which the cokernel is obvious. In particular, we can apply row and column operations to $A$.

At this point, we'll put $A$ in [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) as is suggested in the linked question.

$$A = \newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand{\emat}{\end{pmatrix}}
\bmat
5 & -5 \\
-2 & 4 \\
-4 & 4 \\
1 & 1 \\
\emat.
$$
First we'll swap the first and last rows, and subtract the first row from the rest to make all the rest of the entries in the first column 0:
$$\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand{\emat}{\end{pmatrix}}
\bmat
1 & 1 \\
0 & 6 \\
0 & 8 \\
0 & -10 \\
\emat.
$$
Now subtract the first column from the second, to get
$$\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand{\emat}{\end{pmatrix}}
\bmat
1 & 0 \\
0 & 6 \\
0 & 8 \\
0 & -10 \\
\emat.
$$
Subtract the second row from the third and swap them, to get
$$\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand{\emat}{\end{pmatrix}}
\bmat
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
0 & 6 \\
0 & -10 \\
\emat.
$$
Now zero the last two rows using the second row:
$$\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand{\emat}{\end{pmatrix}}
\bmat
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\emat.
$$
Thus $G\cong \ZZ^4/(e_1,2e_2)\cong \ZZ/2\ZZ\times \ZZ^2$.

Edit: to elaborate, since we made $A$ essentially diagonal, the cokernel splits as a direct sum:
$$\ZZ^4/(e_1,2e_2) = (\ZZ/\ZZ)\oplus (\ZZ/2\ZZ) \oplus (\ZZ/0) \oplus (\ZZ/0) = \ZZ/2\ZZ \times \ZZ^2.$$

Comment: @jgon this made sense up until the  last point do you mean to say $\mathbb{Z}^4/ {( \mathbb{Z} \times 2  \mathbb{Z } ) } $ which is $\mathbb{Z}^3 \times \mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: I was inspired by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243829/smith-normal-form-and-quotient-mathbbz3-m-mathbbz3 where they seem to take $k\mathbb{Z}$ into the denominator of the quotient for each $k$ along the diagonal of the smith normal form (I'm going to review the proof and exact mechanics in a bit so I should be able to prove it myself but wanted to clarify here first)

Comment: I apologize, your answer matches mine too, It seems I forgot that $3-1=2$

Comment: Ah cool, glad it got worked out.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach that amounts to the same thing (row reduction)  using [tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations).

Let's rewrite the group in terms of its presentation (although I will suppress all the commutation relations such as $ab=ba$, $ac=ca$ etc.) Additionally, each $a,b,c,d$ are just standard basis vectors. We get:

$$\langle a,b,c,d: a^{-5}b^4c^4d=1, a^{-5}b^2c^4d=1 \rangle$$

The first thing to note is that we get $d^{-1}=c^{-4}b^{-4}a^5$ (and likewise for the second relation) so we in fact obtain that  $c^{-4}b^{-2}a^{-5}=c^{-4}b^{-4}a^{-5},$ and by cancellation $b^2=1$.

Hence, we can remove $d$ as a generator and replace the relations by $b^2=1$ so the new presentation is
$$\langle a,b,c : b^2=1 \rangle$$

along with the usual commutation relations, or $\mathbb Z^2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.